# Javascript twitter fetcher date format

Tags: javascript, date, twitter

Here is example Twitter Fetcher for website: codepen.io/jasonmayes/pen/Ioype

I try to change date format for tweet.
At this moment is: Posted on 11 Oct 
I would like to get: October 11, 2014
Someone can help me with that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the `function dateFormatter(date)` in line 145 of that javascript file to

```
function dateFormatter(date) {
  switch(date.getMonth()) {
    case 0:
        month="January";
        break;
    case 1:
        month="February";
        break;
    default:
        month="October";
  } 
  return "Posted on "+month+" "+date.getDate()+", "+date.getFullYear();
}
```

Don't forget to complete the `switch`-block.

The `dateFormatter` function is added to a config as seen in line 136.

Comment: Thx for help. You have a beer from me :)